# Are frequency domain and Fourier space the same thing?

Tags: fourier-analysis

What is the difference between frequency domain and Fourier space?

When we perform FFT on an image the result is in "frequency domain", right? How does this relate to Fourier space? I spent some time on Google and I found some people using the two terms interchangeably. However, in page 3 here: http://tinyurl.com/qcfc399 they are presented as different things. So, are they the same or different?

Thank you.

Comment: "The frequency domain" or "frequency space" is just a common name for the Fourier domain. It is a really bad name though since there also exist many other transforms which decompose a signal into "frequency" like components. The sine and cosine functions are really not the only functions which makes sense for a "frequency" interpretation.

Comment: I am new to these topics and confused with "Frequency Domain" and "Fourier Domain".